# Why does this de Bruijn code always return 0s for the last few bits

Tags: python, algorithm, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am computing [cyclic de Bruijn sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence#Construction) using the following code:

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
  n = int(sys.argv[1])  # get n from the command line
else:
  n = 4
N = 2**n
count = 0

def debruijn(x):
  if x.find(x[-n:]) < len(x)-n:  # check if last n chars occur earlier in the string
    return
  if len(x) == N+n-1:
    print(x[:N], x[N:])
    return
  debruijn(x+"0")
  debruijn(x+"1")


x = "0"*n
debruijn(x)
print("sequences")
```

This gives:

```
0000100110101111 000
0000100111101011 000
0000101001101111 000
0000101001111011 000
[...]
```

as the output. Why is `x[N:]` always equal to 000? There doesn't seem to be anything in the code that would guarantee this.

---

Posted to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3339778/why-does-searching-for-a-non-cyclic-de-bruijn-sequence-always-give-you-a-cyclic as requested by @Prune

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a *cyclic* sequence: the last (n-1) bits, by definition, match the first (n-1) bits.  `x[:(n-1)] == x[-(n-1):]`

Since you forced your first digits to `0000`, the "last" three are `000`.  Try changing your initial sequence and see:

```
debruijn("0110")
```

Output:

```
0110000100111101 011
0110000101001111 011
0110000101111010 011
0110000111101001 011
0110010000111101 011
0110010100001111 011
0110010111101000 011
0110011110100001 011
0110100001011110 011
0110100001111001 011
0110100101111000 011
0110100111100001 011
0110101111000010 011
0110101111001000 011
0110111100001010 011
0110111100101000 011
```

**Why does it work?**

Your only check in the code is to see whether the current last-4 sequence has been used already.  Why does this suffice to guarantee wrap-around success?

All by itself, it doesn't: you could easily begin with `00001000`, consuming the `1000` sequence you want at the tail.  However, if you *do* use up that sequence early, then you won't be able to extend the partial sequence to 16 bits.  It's trivial with four matching bits: the 7-bit sequence `0001000` is now a dead end.  It takes a little more work to prove it out for other starts, but it's the same general principle: the *only* ones that make it to the full 16 bits are *forced* to have saved needed wrap-around sequences.

Look at the `0110` case to see the range of possibilities: the various solutions employ both 1-bit ends, all four 2-bit ends, and six of the eight 3-bit ends (`100` and its complement, `011` won't work because of their combinatorial overlap with `0110`).

Comment: True but the code just seems to search for a sequence of length `N+n-1` that has the de Bruijn property non-cyclically. That is it checks x.find(x[-n:]) < len(x)-n.  How does this make it a cyclic sequence?

Comment: What I mean is that the code doesn't seem to do a cyclic check anywhere.  And yet somehow we get a cyclic de Bruijn sequence.

Comment: That's because the check algorithm *works*.  If the sequence starts with `0000`, then the wrap-around *must* be `1000`.

Comment: I sense that what you're asking for is to delve into the theory that *causes* the algorithm to be correct?  That would be for another Stack Exchange site, perhaps the mathematics group?